# Colocar valor padrão em Textarea's caso estiverem vazios

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho dois `textarea` na minha página a dar *GET* ao valor que tenho na minha base de dados e quero que ao eliminar o texto dos dois `textarea` automaticamente colocasse um valor padrão lá "dentro".

Comment: Se for algo (somente) visual você pode utilizar `placeholder='valor padrão'`, sem a necessidade de Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com JQuery você pode fazer isso no evento [`.change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/), esse evento é acionado quando o valor de um elemento é alterado. Nesse evento poderá ser verificado se o `textarea` está vazio, se estiver, colocamos um valor padrão.

```
$('#text1').change(function(){
    if( $("#text1").val().length < 1){
        $('#text1').val('Valor padrão');
      }
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lrj5c42/2/)</kbd>

Para versões anteriores ao IE9 isso pode ser feito através do evento [`onpropertychange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
$('#text1').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    if( $("#text1").val().length < 1){
        $('#text1').val('Valor padrão');
      }
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsykcceb/)</kbd>